# ASP.NET MVC, save search criteria

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) application, like movie sample.
In the list.aspx page I have a grid, the grid has information from the database.
I can fill the grid by search criteria.

For example, I select `product.cost < 60`, I commit. The grid is filled with product, where product cost<60.

After I click to details to view details of one product from result set.
After I click on Back to list (`html.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index"`). And in this moment generated my question. Because, will be shown all products.

What is the best way to save previous search criteria? (I need, when I click to "back to list", previously saved search criteria).

Comment: hello, people, many-many thanks for answers. I have one question, about profiles. What do you think, it is good idea solve this problem using profiles, or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass search criteria parameters  as query string ex: `<%= Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Search", new {var=value1,var2=value2 }, new { })%>`

or you can also save criteria into Session object, but I think that passing it as query string is better solution for you.

Comment: please, can you prefer to me , where can i read about session objects?

Comment: You find info about it here: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Application-and-Session-Objects-in-ASP.NET/

Comment: Session state can be used in the same way like in ASP.NET webforms, see: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/57/session/

Comment: anonymous users preferences also can be saved in session?

Comment: Yes. You can save current user (anonymous too) settings

Answer (score 0):

Place your search criterion on a Stack.  Then  you can just pop off as you have 'used' the criteria, and so get back to the previous criteria you have.

Comment: as I understand, save each query in database. and pop it by userid.

Comment: No, I'd just use a Stack object.  Don't bother saving it to a database, because each time you run your app, queries might be different, unless I've misunderstood the way you app seems to work.

Comment: @Tony: Stack object? What it is?

Comment: Here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx

Comment: Tony - out of curiosity, would you then put this information in the user's session?

Comment: @Andrew, Yes I'd save in the users session.  Why do you ask?

Comment: @Tony - I ask mostly because that may not have been obvious to loviji =)